# Error in brglm model with Backward elimination with Interaction: error in do.call("glm.control", control) : second argument must be a list

Tags: r, glm

After fitting a model with `glm` I got this as a result:

> Warning message:
> glm.fit: Adjusted probabilities with numerical value 0 or 1.**

After some research on Google, I tried with the `brglm` package. When I try to apply backward elimination on the model, I get the following error:

> Error in do.call("glm.control", control) : second argument must be a list.

I searched on Google but I didn't find anything.

Here is my code with `brglm`:

```
library(mlbench)
#require(Amelia)
library(caTools)
library(mlr)
library(ciTools)
library(brglm)

data("BreastCancer")
data_bc <- BreastCancer
data_bc
head(data_bc)
dim(data_bc)

#Delete id column
data_bc<- data_bc[,-1]
data_bc
dim(data_bc)
str(data_bc)
# convert all factors columns to be numeric except class.

for(i in 1:9){
  data_bc[,i]<- as.numeric(as.character(data_bc[,i]))
}

str(data_bc)
#convert class: benign and malignant to binary 0 and 1: 
data_bc$Class<-ifelse(data_bc$Class=="malignant",1,0)    

# now convert class to factor
data_bc$Class<- factor(data_bc$Class, levels = c(0,1))
str(data_bc)

model <- brglm(formula = Class~.^2, data = data_bc, family = "binomial", 
               na.action = na.exclude )
summary(model)

#Backward Elimination:
final <- step(model, direction = "backward")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this by using the `brglm2` package, which supersedes the `brglm` package anyway:

```
model <- glm(formula = Class~.^2, data = na.omit(data_bc), family = "binomial", 
               na.action = na.fail, method="brglmFit" )
final <- step(model, direction = "backward")
length(coef(model)) ## 46
length(coef(final)) ## 42
setdiff(names(coef(model)), names(coef(final))
## [1] "Cl.thickness:Epith.c.size" "Cell.size:Marg.adhesion"  
## [3] "Cell.shape:Bl.cromatin"    "Bl.cromatin:Mitoses"
```

Some general concerns about your approach:

- stepwise reduction is one of the *worst* forms of model reduction (cf. lasso, ridge, elasticnet ...)
- in the presence of missing data, model comparison (e.g. by AIC) is questionable, as different models will be fitted to different subsets of the data.  Given that you are only going to lose a small fraction of your data by using `na.omit()` (comparing `nrow(bc_data)` with `sum(complete.cases(bc_data))`, I would **strongly** recommend dropping observations with NA values from the data set before starting
- it's also not clear to me that comparing penalized models via AIC is statistically appropriate (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88398/model-selection-with-firth-logistic-regression))

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've just tried it. The error that was displayed with brglm is no longer displayed. But now I get the same model even after applying step. Do you please have another method to recommend?

Comment: I also removed the variable with missing value

Comment: sorry, that's not what I got. See edits.)